# JQuery on click - select all items with the same class and remove a certain class from them all and add to the clicked item (active effects)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a library of CSS buttons and now I am building an extension (I prefer small modules rather than lots of big files). The base class for the buttons is .btns-button and then further classes are applied to give style them further.

I have a .btns-active class that I would like applied on click. I cannot target by ID as this is a library designed to be used in any project.

I am building a demo page and trying to apply .btns-active to the button that is clicked whilst removing it from any other buttons with .btns-active already applied.

```css
.btns-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button class='btns-button btns-red-bottom btns-active' href='#'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-blue-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-green-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-orange-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-purple-bottom'>Click Me</button>
```

This is within the CSS file (that is generated using SCSS). Coloured bottoms, basically just adds a 4px bottom border to the button and the colour of choice.

.active-btns makes a white BG and Black text, set to important - it works fine as I applied it to the first button to test. When one of the buttons is clicked I would like .btns-active to clear from any buttons that have it set and to be applied only to the one that has been clicked. I have tried numerous JQuery methods - I have spent a while searching here and none of the solutions have worked for me, here's an attempt (which isn't working):

```
$('.btns-button').on("click", function (){
    $('.btns-button').removeClass('btns-active');
    $(this).addClass('btns-active');
});
```

Comment: You could use `$('.btns-button').removeClass('btns-active')`.

Comment: Sorry, that is actually in there, I was playing around with it (made a button variable), hence why that 'button' was still there in place of $('.btns-button') - it isn't working for some reason.

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you? Does the 'btns-active' class persist on the old elements or does the new one not get the class?

Comment: If nothing is hapening consider to execute your code after the load event:
`window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
$('.btns-button').on("click", function (){
    $('.btns-button').removeClass('btns-active');
    $(this).addClass('btns-active');
});
})`
PS: Sorry for spam..

Comment: My bad - stupid question and now solved. The issue a typo when linking to JQuery in the first place - now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `.siblings(.class)` to reference all controls with the same class next to it, for this case it should always be just 1 button found and we remove the class from that button

[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .siblings() method allows us to search through the siblings of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it.

```js
$('.btns-button').on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass('btns-active') //add class to clicked button
         .siblings(".btns-active") //look for any other button at the same level
         .removeClass('btns-active'); //remove the class from the found button
});
```

```css
.btns-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btns-active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btns-button btns-red-bottom btns-active' href='#'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-blue-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-green-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-orange-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-purple-bottom'>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well clear all the button then apply to the corrent one

```
$('.btns-button').on("click", function (){
$('.btns-active').removeClass('btns-active');
$(this).addClass('btns-active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cache references

```
var $buttons = $('.btns-button');

$buttons.on('click', function () {

  $buttons.removeClass('btns-active');

  $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

example: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jonivijabu/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this isn't working either - would it help to take a look at the page in question as every JQuery or JS method I have tried is simply not working.

Comment: pease use `var` if you init a variable.

Comment: @D.Winning check my example. Your bug might be somewhere else. How do you define styling on `.active-btns`?

Comment: My bad - stupid question and now solved. The issue a typo when linking to JQuery in the first place - now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Be shure to execute your code AFTER evrything is loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
  $('.btns-button').on("click", function (){
      $('.btns-button').removeClass('btns-active');
      $(this).addClass('btns-active');
  });
})
```

```css
.btns-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  transition: 0.5s; }
  
  
  .btns-active {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btns-button btns-red-bottom btns-active' href='#'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-blue-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-green-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-orange-bottom'>Click Me</button>
<button class='btns-button btns-purple-bottom'>Click Me</button>
```